# Etiquetas y Sinónimos

Tags: soporte

He visto que hay

> etiquetas y sinónimos

en Stack Overflow...

¿Se pueden crear nuevas etiquetas o nuevos sinónimos? ¿Que reputación necesito?

He visto también que se pueden "aprobar sinónimos de etiquetas" ¿Como se realiza esto?

**Mi primera pregunta**... quizás algo extraña...

perdon si no es el sitio correcto !!

Answer (score 1):

Una de las preguntas... la "auto-respondo"...

Se necesitan 300 ptos para poder crear nuevas etiquetas.